# Display dynamic Content in Magento Static Block

Tags: cache, cms, static-block, magento-1.9.3.2

I have declared a static block in Magento 1.9.3.2 named 'subcategory_listing' that has the following code:

```
{{block type="subcategory/listing" name="subcategory.listing"  template="category/subcategory.listing.phtml"}}
```

This block is set on Category View as Display Setings->Static Block Only -> Subcategory Listing (my block) and it has to display all subcategories.
The problem is When I have `Blocks HTML output` enabled. In this situation  my block displays the same output when i change categories:

```
if I get first in Category 1, I get:
Ex: Category 1: Subcategories from category 1
Category 2: Subcategory from Category 1

if I get first in Category 2, I get:
Category 2: Subcategories from category 2
Category 1: Subcategory from Category 2
```

I've read that it is a cache problem but I can't get it. Any ideas?

UPDATE:

category/subcategory.listing.phtml

```
<?php $count = 0; ?>
    <?php foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) { ?>
        <div class="row section main_prod_section <?php echo (++$count%2 ? "reg_bg" : "text-right grey_bg");  ?>">
            <div class="col-sm-6 prod_image_wrapper">
                <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$subcategory->getListingImage(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $subcategory->getName()?>" class="pr_img">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 info_wrapper vertical-center">
                <h2 class="title"><?php echo $subcategory->getName()?></h2>
                <p><?php echo $subcategory->getDescription() ?></p>
                <a href="<?php echo $subcategory->getUrl() ?>" class="main_btn">Descoperă</a>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- end section -->
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: What's in the template file?

Comment: Please see the UPDATE.

Comment: Do you have the block cache turned on?

Comment: I've Tried to add ` protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->addData(array(
            'cache_lifetime' => 3600,
            'cache_tags'     => array(Mage_Cms_Model_Block::CACHE_TAG,Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::CACHE_TAG),
            'cache_key'      => Mage::registry('current_category')->getId(),
        ));
    }`  and dosn't displays anything at all.

Comment: All caches are enabled

Comment: As I said, if I desable Blocks HTML output cache it works just fine.

Comment: This is the expected behaviour.  A static block is cached the first time you access it. Try adding cache_lifetime=0  in your block

Comment: I've tried, and dosn;t fix anything